# R_ How to put a variable in a name

Tags: r, variables, naming-conventions

I have 50 files to read in R and I created this loop to help me. I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this in R.
How can I write it properly in R?

```
library(foreign)    
for(i in 1:50 ){
      tpi <- read.dbf('toto_%i%')
     }
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the function `paste`. As written your loop will overwrite tpi everytime it increments, so you will want to use a `list` to store the data.

```
toto = list()
for(i in 1:50)
{
    toto[i] = read.dbf(paste0("toto_", i))
}
```

A shortcut using `lapply` gets the same results:

```
toto = lapply(1:50, function(x) read.dbf(paste0("toto_", x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `lapply`

```
lst <- lapply(1:50, function(i) read.dbf(paste0("toto_", i)))
```